# Pendrive not seen at all

Tags: usb-flash-drive

Yesterday I tried to format my pendrive Corsair Flash Voyager 32GB. I got a message saying Windows couldn't delete all the files, then apparently it deleted everything and I couldn't open it, there was no data bar, just "FAT32" (I think), and after a while it disappeared completely.

I'm pretty sure it hasn't been damaged. The thing is, when I plug it in, I hear the sound and see it in My Computer for a fraction of a second, but that's it. I can't even see it in Disk Management. The only place it can be seen is Device Manager, where I can install drivers (the newest one is already installed) and add volumes(there aren't any but when I try to add one('Wypelnij' button), it is just empty and after reopening the window it's gone again)

[image]

I don't know what to do, since most of solutions on the Internet assume it can be seen in Disk Managament.

[image: disk managament]

[image: device manager]
edit: neither rufus nor EaseUs detects it

Comment: Can you try Rufus software, and look if it detects your USB flash.

Comment: Try another partition manager.  EaseUS is a good one and is free.  I hate that Microsoft chose to hide certain drive types.

Comment: Or DiskGenius, https://www.diskgenius.com/, also free

Comment: none of them work :/

Answer (score 1):

Try diskpart to clean the disk.

```
> diskpart
> list disk (see which disk you want)
> select disk x
> clean
```

After this the drive won't be initialized or have any partitions. You can either continue using diskpart to create a primary partition and assign a drive letter, or you can run diskmgmt.msc and do it through the gui.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Nope, It still bugs :(
https://imgur.com/a/CbtXh7a
"brak nosnika w urzadzeniu" means no device connected